# Gaufrette use Service Adapter

Tags: symfony, gaufrette

I use KnpGaufrette Bundle and I'd like to use the service adapter.#

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/adapters/service.md

```
app/config/config.yml
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        foo:
            service:
                id:     my.adapter.service
```

But I'dont know how to start to create my own gaufrette adapter (my.adapter.service)in my projet. Can you please give me an hint.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a custom Gaufrette Adapter , you have to implement the [`Gaufrette\Adapter`](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/src/Gaufrette/Adapter.php) Interface.

Once you have your custom Adapter, you can create a Symfony Service for it and use it as a Graurfette Service Adapter.